# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I wrote the "bubble sort" function to sort a list of images. I can't understand why the function returns the "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".
Can anyone help me?

```
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    var list = $j("dt").find("a").find("img");

    bubbleSort(list, list.size());    
});


function bubbleSort(a, size)
{
    do {
        var swapped = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            var img = getAlt(a, i);
            var img2 = getAlt(a, i + 1);

            if (img > img2) {
                var temp = a[i].attr('src');
                a[i].attr('src') = a[i + 1].attr('src');
                a[i + 1].attr('src') = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped); // <----- line error
}

function getAlt(list, pos) {
    var img = list[pos].attr("alt");
    img = img.split(' ');
    return img[3];
}
```

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: a[i].attr('src') = a[i+1].attr('src'); and a[i+1].attr('src') = temp; are not valid instructions

Comment: JavaScript has `.sort` for arrays which uses binary sort. You can supply a custom order function. Like: `[1, 2].sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; });`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `list[pos]` use `list.eq(pos)` since with the first one you get a raw HTML element (which has no `attr` function) and the second way you get a jQuery object (which has an `attr` function)

Also use `list.length` instead of `list.size()` since the `size` function has been deprecated since version 1.8

Finally as noted by M. Page

```
a[i].attr('src') = a[i + 1].attr('src');
```

should be

```
a.eq(i).attr('src', a.eq(i + 1).attr('src'));
```

and the same goes for statements like it

You should also consider altering your `getAlt` function in the event that the img does not have an alt attribute

```
function getAlt(list, pos) {
    var img = list.eq(pos).attr("alt") || "";    
    if(img) {
        img = img.split(' ');
    }
    return img[3] || "";
}
```

All of these changes can be found in the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ejhq03qy/1/

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, since that would cause the described error, but `.size()` is a supported jQuery method.

Comment: ...oh nevermind. Just saw that it's [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/). So it should indeed be changed. Sorry.

Comment: I made ​​the changes but the code generates a loop. I chose to follow another way. I put all the "alt" images in an array, and after I used ".sort () + .revert ()". Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[i].attr('src') = a[i+1].attr('src');
```

has to be written:

```
a[i].attr('src', a[i+1].attr('src'));
```

Same for line below.